# Counting the occurrences of a string in a cell array of strings in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, count

I have two cell arrays of strings of varying lengths, d={'nerve','body','muscle','bone'} and e={'body','body','muscle'}. I have to compare these two arrays and count the occurrences of each string in e in d. The expected result should be a vector, count_string=(0,2,1,0).
The following is the code I've written but I get the error:Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object. I am a beginner in matlab programming. Any quick help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
count_string=size(d)
for i=1:length(d)    
count_string{i}=sum(ismember(e{i},d));
end
```

After all your below suggestions, this is the module i have.

```
for i=1:length(d_union)
count_string1=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d1,x)), d_union);
count_string2=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d2,x)), d_union);
count_string3=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d3,x)), d_union);
count_string4=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d4,x)), d_union);
count_string5=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d5,x)), d_union);
count_string6=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d6,x)), d_union);
count_string7=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d7,x)), d_union);
count_string8=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d8,x)), d_union);
count_string9=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d9,x)), d_union);
count_string10=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d10,x)), d_union);
count_string11=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d11,x)), d_union);
count_string12=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d12,x)), d_union);
count_string13=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(d13,x)), d_union);
count_string14=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(testdoc,x)), d_union);    end
```

My matlab compiler is taking forever to execute this module. 'd_union' is a 1x1216 cell array and each of the d1 to testdoc is approximately 1x240 cell array. I gotta calculate the cosine similarity of the vectors I get from the above operation. Is there a way to speed up the process? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you *have* to use strings? It looks like the number of possible strings you have is quite low; couldn't you just replace each string with a number? That would probably speed things up a lot!

Comment: Well, I have to use strings. I'm reading from a text file that has several document paragraphs, d1 to d13. I have to use these to perform other calculations. So, I'm not sure replacing each string with a number would work fine for me. Is there any other method?

Comment: You don't need the for-loop, `cellfun` takes care of that. You just running the same code multiple time with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

You can count occurrences of strings from `d` in `e` like this:

```
count_string = cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(e,x)), d);
```

For your sample data you will get vector [0 2 1 0];

Does the `d` array contain only unique strings?

**UPDATE**:

Here is another method with temporary converting strings to numbers with [GRP2IDX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grp2idx.html) and counting them with [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html). It assumes all strings in `e` are also exist in `d`.

```
[gi g] = grp2idx([d e]);
gn = histc(gi(numel(d)+1:end),1:numel(g));
```

`g` will contain the unique strings (probably will be identical to `d`) and `gn` will be the counts. `gi` is temporary numerical array used for counting.

*You need Statistical Toolbox to access GRP2IDX function.*

Comment: This works perfectly well! Thanks a lot. Yes, d array contains only unique strings. Also, I need to perform this function on 13 other cell arrays of strings each approximately 1x140. Is there a way to speed up the process? I have to calculate the cosine similarity as well for the 13 vectors I get out of the above operation. My matlab compiler is taking forever to execute the code. Can you please help?

Comment: The grp2idx function saved me!I did not know about this before. Another new learning in matlab. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the answer is helpful consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with

```
count_string = cell(1,size(d));
```

And you are indexing into `e`, but controlling the loop on the size of `d`.

```
for i=1:length(d)
   count_string{i}=sum(ismember(d{i},e));
end
```

Comment: I don't have matlab with me right now, but I think this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I tried the above code and 'count_string' displays 1 for each occurrence of the string in e, in d. But how do i count the no.of occurrences of each string? As in, if 'body' appears twice and 'muscle' once in e, then count_string should display (0,2,1,0). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just formatted the answer, didn't changed the code. The first line should be `count_string = zeros(size(d));`. In for-loop: `count_string(i) = ...`. And `d` and `e` should be switched as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the errors with your original for-loop solution, [macduff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371812/52738) already mentioned them:

- You need to initialize `count_string` using either [CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html) or [ZEROS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/zeros.html):

  ```
  count_string = cell(size(d));   %# A 1-by-4 cell array
  %# OR
  count_string = zeros(size(d));  %# A 1-by-4 numeric array
  ```
- When adding values to `count_string`, you should use `()`-indexing for numeric arrays and `{}`-indexing for cell arrays.
- You need to swap `d` and `e` in your call to [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html), and index `d` with the loop variable instead of `e`.

Regarding alternatives to using a loop, [yuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9372217/52738) gave you one solution using [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html). Another vectorized solution is to use a combination of [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
>> [~, index] = ismember(e,d);  %# Find where each entry in e occurs in d
>> count_string = accumarray(index.', 1, [numel(d) 1]).'  %# Accumulate indices

count_string =

     0     2     1     0
```