# MATLAB search cell array for string subset

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I'm trying to find the locations where a substring occurs in a cell array in MATLAB. The code below works, but is rather ugly. It seems to me there should be an easier solution.

```
cellArray = [{'these'} 'are' 'some' 'nicewords' 'and' 'some' 'morewords'];
wordPlaces = cellfun(@length,strfind(cellArray,'words'));
wordPlaces = find(wordPlaces); % Word places is the locations.
cellArray(wordPlaces);
```

This is similar to, but not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371735/counting-the-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-cell-array-of-strings-in-matlab) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing to do is to encapsulate this idea as a function. Either inline:

```
substrmatch = @(x,y) ~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(y,x))

findmatching = @(x,y) y(substrmatch(x,y))
```

Or contained in two m-files:

```
function idx = substrmatch(word,cellarray)
    idx = ~cellfun(@isempty,strfind(word,cellarray))
```

and

```
function newcell = findmatching(word,oldcell)
    newcell = oldcell(substrmatch(word,oldcell))
```

So now you can just type

```
>> findmatching('words',cellArray)
ans = 
    'nicewords'    'morewords'
```

Comment: Cheers! That works, but the thing is I was hoping there'd a be built in function for this, or at least a way to do it in less steps. If someone comes up with something great, if not I'll mark this as a solution in a few hours.

Comment: As far as I know there's no built-in function. I had the same problem myself a while back, and ended up writing these code snippets because I couldn't find a built-in that did what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you would consider it a *simpler* solution than yours, but [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html) are a very good general-purpose utility I often use for searching strings. One way to extract the cells from `cellArray` that contains words with `'words'` in them is as follows:

```
>> matches = regexp(cellArray,'^.*words.*$','match');  %# Extract the matches
>> matches = [matches{:}]                              %# Remove empty cells

matches = 

    'nicewords'    'morewords'
```

Comment: Excellent solution, but I'm terrified of regular expressions. It is less lines of code, but I've marked the above correct as I'd rather avoid regexp. Sorry, that feels a little unfair as this is correct and in a sense simpler.

Comment: @dgmp88: I understand completely. Regular expressions do take some getting used to, but once you get the hang of them you [feel like a superhero](http://xkcd.com/208/). ;)