# string matching in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, computer-vision, signals, signal-processing

I have two short (S with the size of 1x10) and very long (L with the size of 1x1000) strings and I am going to find the locations in L which are matched with S.

[image]

In this specific matching, I am just interested to match some specific strings in S (the black strings). Is there any function or method in matlab that can match some specific strings (for example string numbers of 1, 5, 9 in S)?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for either [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) or [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). There are also a lot of related questions, for example: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428746/matlab-search-cell-array-for-string-subset)... have you checked them out?

Comment: @EitanT: tnx, I edited the question

Comment: And this is a computer vision question because?

Comment: @Franco Callari: yes, it is for pattern matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find substrings in `L` that contain the same letters (characters) as `S` in certain positions (let's say given by array `idx`). Regular expressions are ideal here, so I suggest using `regexp`.

In regular expressions, a dot (`.`) matches any character, and curly braces (`{}`) optionally specify the number of desired occurrences. For example, to match a string of length 6, where the second character is 'a' and the fifth is 'b', our regular expression could be any of the following syntaxes:

```
.a..b.
.a.{2}b.
.{1}a.{2}b.{1}
```

any of these is correct. So let's construct a regular expression pattern first:

```
in = num2cell(diff([0; idx(:); numel(S) + 1]) - 1);  %// Intervals
ch = num2cell(S(idx(:)));                            %// Matched characters
C = [in(:)'; ch(:)', {''}];
pat = sprintf('.{%d}%c', C{:});                      %// Pattern for regexp
```

Now all is left is to feed `regexp` with `L` and the desired pattern:

```
loc = regexp(L, pat)
```

and voila!

#### Example

Let's assume that:

```
S = 'wbzder'
L = 'gabcdexybhdef'
idx = [2 4 5]
```

First we build a pattern:

```
in = num2cell(diff([0; idx(:); numel(S) + 1]) - 1);
ch = num2cell(S(idx(:)));
C = [in(:)'; ch(:)', {''}];
pat = sprintf('.{%d}%c', C{:});
```

The pattern we get is:

```
pat =
    .{1}b.{1}d.{0}e.{1}
```

Obviously we can add code that beautifies this pattern into `.b.de.`, but this is really an unnecessary optimization (`regexp` can handle the former just as well).

After we do:

```
loc = regexp(L, pat)
```

we get the following result:

```
loc =
     2     8
```

Seems correct.

Comment: tnx, but when I use matrix (numbers) it say that Error using cellstr (line 34), Input must be a string. What should I do in this case?

Comment: How I can use these codes in order to find a set of strings in L that [1 5 9] arrays are matched? In other words, I need a set of strings with he length of 10 that their [1 5 9] strings are the same as S.

Comment: Oh, so you want to match substrings in `L` that are similar to S in the [1 5 9] positions?

Comment: exactly. It is like pattern matching, but here I just want to use those specific locations

Comment: @Nicole I've amended my answer.

Comment: It does not work for my example: (please see below)                S = [1     2   NaN];
S = num2str(S);

L = [2     2     1     2     2     1     1     2     2     2];
L = num2str(L);

idx = [1 2];
in = num2cell(diff([0; idx(:); numel(s) + 1]) - 1);
ch = num2cell(s(idx(:)));
C = [in(:)'; ch(:)', {''}];
pat = sprintf('.{%d}%c', C{:});
loc = regexp(l, pat)

Comment: the answer of the above codes is 7, while the correct answer is 3 and 7.

Comment: @Nicole you have a lot of problems with your input. `num2str` inserts spaces between numbers, which also count as a separate character, and you have `NaN`s, which are translated into a `'NaN'` string (3 characters). So in this example, 7 is quite correct.

Comment: @Nicole if you want to fix your input to get `[3 7]`, remove the NaNs from `S` (or replace them with another value, _e.g._ `0`), and use `sprintf` instead of `num2str` to convert `S` and `L` to strings in the following way: `S = sprintf('%d', S)` and `L = sprintf('%d', L)`

Comment: it works now, but not for example for -999 (instead of 0). However, it solves my problem

Comment: @Nicole Of course it won't because 999 are 3 characters. Are you interested in matching number arrays or strings??

Comment: Actually I am going to use string matching for pattern matching. So, I am more interested in array matching. Do you have any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27576/discussion-between-nicole-and-eitan-t)